# Is it safe to store a token in vuex state + persistedState plugin?

Tags: security, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Previously I store tokens on cookies with vue-cookies. However I don't exactly have the idea on how to make them secure (https only) or something, plus the user can easily see them via *Applications* (chrome).

Right now I am storing the user's token in vuex's state, protected by persistedState so that it won't reset everytime the user refreshes the page. It is also invisible on the average user.

Is this an "okay" or good approach?

PS: I'm only storing the token, not the user's information or anything

Comment: The token stored in any way of form can be read by the user if he wants to. So the only reason that it wouldn't be safe is that you store critical information in the token.

Comment: And even in the vue mastery online course they are storing the token the this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This practice is fine. Especially if you're storing only the token, you can verify the information elsewhere. For example, I'm storing a user token in the state which is then verified against a back-end with a database containing additional information related to the token. As long as you feel users are not a threat if they explicitly know their own or someone else's token, you shouldn't worry.